# Algorithm to divide key value pairs into n groups of sum y or smaller

Tags: python, language-agnostic

I have a key-value pair like this:

```
'NANOUSDT.csv.gz': 15,
'ENJUSDT.csv.gz': 19,
'DGBBTC.csv.gz': 0,
'BTSUSDT.csv.gz': 1,
'BLZBTC.csv.gz': 42,
'BANDUSDT.csv.gz': 14,
'ETCUSDT.csv.gz': 202
```

It contains over around 300 items. Some are big. Some are small. I want to create a list of list of keys with the following conditions:

1. The sum of the values in a list cannot exceed 10,000
2. A list cannot contain more than 8 elements

No single item has a size over 10,000.

How can i acheive this?

Comment: Is this an assignment problem?

Comment: No. I am trying to process multiple files in multithread. I need to open the file and process.  I cannot exceed my CPU cores/RAM while opening. 10000 is the place holder for my RAM limit and 8 is the placeholder for my processor core limit. Thought this would be an interesting problem too.

Comment: See the Knapsack problem, it's an NP-complete. You can find many performant algorithme that results in efficient combinasons. The "best" combinaison needs to be compared to all other, but the number of combinations (complexity) is factorial (n!).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```py
kvs = {'1': 9999,
       '2': 19,
       '3': 0,
       '4': 1,
       '5': 42,
       '6': 14,
       '7': 14,
       '8': 14,
       '9': 14,
       '10': 14,
       '11': 10000}
buckets = []
cur_bucket = []
weight_so_far = 0
for k, v in kvs.items():
    if len(cur_bucket) == 8 or weight_so_far + v > 10000:
        buckets.append(cur_bucket)
        cur_bucket = []
        weight_so_far = 0
    weight_so_far += v
    cur_bucket.append(k)
if cur_bucket:
    buckets.append(cur_bucket)

print(buckets)
```

Output

```
[['1'], ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'], ['10'], ['11']]
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes. But, I would prefer it if the groups are smarter. By smart I mean, having as few number of groups as possible. In your example if [1,3,4] was in the same group the number of groups could had been smaller if the dictionary was bigger.

Comment: @DanielSmith In that case, this problem is an instance of [bin packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem).

Comment: Thank you. That's the exact thing.